# Python のコードでエラーが発生する理由が分からない

Tags: python

初めて二日目の初心者です。真似をしながら書いたつもりなのですがエラーが発生し理由がわからないので良ければ教えてください。

```
n= int(input("気温を入力：")
if n>=35:
  print("猛暑日")
elif n>=30:
  print("真夏日")
elif n>=25:
  print("夏日")
else:
    print("熱くない")
```

Comment: 「真似をしながら」とは何か書籍等を参考にされたのでしょうか？であれば解説などありませんか？　「エラーが発生し」だけでは分かりませんのでエラーメッセージを追記してください。 また、コードはマークダウンで記述してください（Pythonはインデントが重要です）。

Answer (score 1):

`)`が足りないですね。

```py
n= int(input("気温を入力：")
↓
n= int(input("気温を入力："))
```